# Adding Display Suite fields to Search API results

Tags: 8, search, display-suite

### Problem

I have some Display Suite token fields, and I want to include these and other entity fields in the Search API search results.

I also want to include the Search API `Excerpt` field in the results.

What's the easiest way to get these DS fields into the search results along with other entity fields?

### What I've tried

I have tried using `Fields` for the view's `Format > Show` setting, but the DS fields don't appear as field options.

I have tried using `Rendered entity` for the view's `Format > Show` setting, but the `Excerpt` field doesn't appear as a field option in any of the display configurations.

I have tried adding custom theme templates to override the display, and I get a fatal error.  I haven't resolved this error after a bit of searching, so theme overrides doesn't look like the easiest route.

```
When a #lazy_builder callback is specified, no properties can exist; all properties must be generated by the #lazy_builder callback. You specified the following properties: #attributes.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed it earlier, but it turns out that Search API [just exposed the Excerpt field to view modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/2983606).

Updating Search API to `8.x-1.x-dev` and a cache rebuild gave me the functionality I need.